# Verifying email using playwright

Tags: playwright

I'm using `mail7.io`

The problem is it's not clicking in the "confirm my account" link. The locator is correct. Playwright is not able to locate it for some reason.
Do we need to add the scrolling logic? the page has a vertical scroll bar and the link is in the bottom of the page. I've even tried added the JS logic to scrolling to the bottom. didn't work.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
const emailPage = await this.browser.newPage();

await emailPage.goto(`https://console.mail7.io/admin/inbox/inbox?username=${email}`, {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
});

await emailPage.waitForSelector('.subject:has-text("Verify your email")');
await emailPage.click('.subject:has-text("Verify your email")');

const confirmLink = await emailPage.waitForSelector('a:has-text("Confirm my account")');
await confirmLink.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
await confirmLink.click();
```

Expected output: playwright clicks on the confirm my account link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to scroll down your page to click on the button. The problem is that the content of the email opens in a new iframe. So you need to get the content of this iframe with [contentFrame()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-content-frame).

```
await emailPage.waitForSelector('.subject:has-text("Verify your email")');
await emailPage.click('.subject:has-text("Verify your email")');

const iframe = await emailPage.waitForSelector('.message iframe');
const iframeContent = await iframe.contentFrame();
  
const confirmLink = await iframeContent.waitForSelector('a:has-text("Confirm my account")');
await confirmLink.click();
```